# Mysql Replicating mysql (all) database - Weird issue

Tags: mysql

So I've setup replication which will replicate all database including MySQL from the master.

I've created a new `user@localhost` without password account on master, it immediately reflects on replication. Both are 5.7 and binded to their own ip and have skip-name-resolve

When i try to access that account from master, it says access denied. If I try that account from slave server, it works.

I've even tried changing it to `'user'@'%'` but still it only works from slave. Doesn't work from master. I want that account to work from both master and slave. That account has grants for only `USAGE`.

`EDIT:`

If I set password, then it works on both server as `user@localhost`. Without password it only works in slave server (created 2 test accounts on master now). Why is that?

Update:

I create user like this, I can login from master server but I have to press return key.

```
  `create user `user@localhost` identified by '';`

   master_server@root: mysql -uuser -p
   <-- Enter key, logins fine.

   slave_server@root: mysql -uuser
   logins without the need of -p switch.
```

Update:

hmm, There was a my.cnf in home directory, deleted it and works fine.

Comment: You say it works on the slave, but when you log in, what does `SHOW GRANTS;` show you for your user@host? I'm guessing it thinks you're `''@'localhost'` (empty string username) or similar.

Comment: no. its not the case. it shows user@local host. 
But I found something, updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

If any hidden .my.cnf exist in home directory with other username and password will cause such issue.

Delete any .my.cnf in user home directory.

```
     ls -a ~/
```